# Does an ionic app always use internal storage of android device to store data? I am using pouchdb without SQLite adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2, pouchdb

I want to check, what is the free space available for my application so that I can warn the user to free up some storage to use the app further. This is a data collection app. I have used `pouchdb` version 6.2.0

When memory is getting full the following errors are occurring. I am handling these errors but still the app is behaving weired. not showing any existing data. When I restart the app, still I can not see the data. After freeing some space I see the data but losing recently filled data.

Errors:

While putting data:

`{“status”: 500, “name”: “indexed_db_went_bad”, “message”: “unknown”, “reason”: “QuotaExceededError”}`

While getting data:

`InvalidStateError: Failed to execute ‘transaction’ on ‘IDBDatabase’: The database connection is closing`

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN docs on Storage API under "Quotas and usage estimates". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API#Quotas_and_usage_estimates

```
navigator.storage.estimate().then(estimate => {
  // estimate.quota is the estimated quota
  // estimate.usage is the estimated number of bytes used
});
```

I'm just starting to look into this myself, hoping I can recover the databases.